# Error code 91 Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to perform a web automation, which involves logging in and search for a particular text on my spreadsheet on to particular box  on the webpage.
I'm Encountering an error in  the 2nd step to paste the value on to the  search box in the webpage.

Error Line in the code :

```
EnterName.value = Firstname
```

I have tried logging in and this step is successful.however, the second step was not.

```
Public IE as Object
Public Entername as Object
Public HTMLdoc as Object

Sub Pink()
'logging in to webpage

   username1 = Activeworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").range("B2").value
   password1 = Activeworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").range("B3").value

' Opening IE explorer

Set IE =  New InternetExplorerMedium

With IE
  . Visible = true
  . navigate "website"
  while .Busy or .readyState<>4:DoEvents: Wend
End With

'Actual login
Dim Login as object
Dim password as Object

Set Login = HTML.getElementsByName("Username")(0)
Set password = HTML.getElementsByName("Password")(0)

Login.Value = username1
password.Value = password1

HTMLdoc.forms(0).submit

With  IE

while .Busy or .readyState<>4:DoEvents: Wend
End With

call Step2

End sub

************************************************************************
Sub Step2()

Firstname = Range("A8").value

lastName = Range("C8").value 

set  EnterName =  HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("PRIMARY")(0)

EnterName.value =  Firstname

End sub 

********************************************************************

IE11 Inspect Elements

<input name ="PRIMARY" tableindex="0" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner"
id  ="indium_view_form_ValidationTextbox_0" aria-invalid="false" aria-
required="true" type="text"  maxlenght="1000" autocomplete="off" data
dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusnode" value=""></input>
```

I expected the value in range("A8")  to be pasted on the IE webpage.  However i get an error 91. Object variable or with block variable not set

Comment: Corrections :Set Login = HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("Username")(0)
                     Set password = HTMLdoc.getElementsByName("Password")(0)

Answer (score 0):

You never instantiate `HTMLDoc` as `New HTMLDocument`. You need to do that. I would therefore expect your code to error before the mentioned line.

You also refer to `HTML` variable which I don't see declared or instantiated. I expect these two variables should be just one and passed to the second sub as an argument.

```
HTML.getElementsByName("Username")(0)
```

Use `Option Explicit` at the top of all your modules to check for these sorts of errors.

---

I would also pass `HTMLDoc` and the worksheet as arguments to the second sub rather than using public variables.

---

And note that you are using implicit `Activesheet` references as you don't full qualify your ranges so this is  error prone.

```
Range("A8").Value
```

The above has no explicit worksheet reference. The following example uses an explicit reference:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A8").Value
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196115/discussion-on-answer-by-qharr-error-code-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variab).

Comment: I took a closer look at the html code, I believe u were right, it's within an iframe.

Comment: Can u help me with this, cos I'm new to iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the [Object variable not set (Error 91)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-variable-not-set-error-91):  There are two steps to creating an object variable. First, you must declare the object variable. Then you must assign a valid reference to the object variable using the Set statement.

So, after creating the Htmldoc object, we need to assign a valid reference to.

I have tried to create a sample using the following code, you could refer to it.

```
Public IE As Object
Public Entername As Object
Public Htmldoc As Object

Sub Test()

username1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main Page").Range("B2").Value
password1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main Page").Range("B3").Value

Dim Rank As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate ("http://localhost:54382/HtmlPage47.html")
Do
    If IE.readyState = 4 Then
        Exit Do
    Else
    End If
Loop

Set Htmldoc = IE.document

Dim Login As Object
Dim password As Object

Set Login = Htmldoc.getElementsByName("Username")(0)
Set password = Htmldoc.getElementsByName("Password")(0)

Login.Value = username1
password.Value = password1

Htmldoc.forms(0).submit
With IE

While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
End With

Call Step2

End Sub


Sub Step2()

Firstname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main Page").Range("A8").Value

Set Entername = Htmldoc.getElementsByName("PRIMARY")(0)

Entername.Value = Firstname

End Sub
```

Code in the web page:

```
<form>
    <div>
        <input name="Username" id="Text1" type="text" /><br />
        <input name="Password" id="Text1" type="text" /><br />
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" /><br />
        <input name="PRIMARY" tableindex="0" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" id="indium_view_form_ValidationTextbox_0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" type="text" maxlenght="1000" autocomplete="off" datadojo-attach-point="textbox,focusnode" value=""></input>
    </div>
</form>
```